# Class is not being removed

Tags: jquery, prestashop-1.6

I'm using PrestaShop 1.6. In my tpl file I add the hidden class to span as shown

```html
<span name="bl" id="bl" class="badge hidden">
  <i class="icon-remove"></i> 
  {l s='Gift wrapping'}
</span>
```

In the footer.tpl, using javascript, I made this code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ckbox = $('#gift');

  $('input').on('click',function () {
    if (ckbox.is(':checked')) {
      alert('hidden test');
      $('#bl').removeClass('hidden');
    } 
  });
});
```

The `alert` is shown when the input is checked, but the problem is that the `removeClass()` function has no effect or I would like remove the hidden class when it's checked. Any ideas please?

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the same id of `bl`?

Comment: no , either i have changed the id many times

Comment: Did you try debugger to see if the removeClass is called and class is removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code should work, if your checkbox is an input, but try this to be more specific on the selector (I've also added `.show()` and `.hide()` which you may not need if the `css` is set correctly):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#gift').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#bl').removeClass('hidden').show();
        } else {
            $('#bl').addClass('hidden').hide();
        }
    });
});
```